# Regex to find Match after multiple Lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to find the count of  error logs occured for each Service. This log file is very large. But the log Pattern goes as below:

```
[DEFService@]: connect failed: not authorized to connect
WARNING: Closing connection from <ipaddress>>  due to timeout, exceeded timeout of 20.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
[ABCService]: connect failed: not authorized to connect
WARNING: Connection timeouts delayed around 15 seconds.
WARNING: Closing connection from <ipaddress>>  due to timeout, exceeded timeout of 20.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
[XYZService@]: connect failed: not authorized to connect
WARNING: Closing connection from <<ipaddress>> due to timeout, exceeded timeout of 20.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
[DEFService@]: connect failed: not authorized to connect
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open 

files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
ERROR: Accept() failed:  many open files. Please check each process and system limits on the number of open files.
```

The above error message "many open files" , has occured many times for each Service, I need to  take the count of every Service , How many times the "many open files" error message has occured for that Service. For eg. `DEFService`.

I have tried: `(DEFService.*)$(\r\n)(.*many open files.*)`.
I got the count for "DEFService" as 1 as there is only occurence of "many open files" error message just the next line after the Service Name, but the actual count is 2, as there is one more, but one Warning line in between, due to which the Regex is not recognising, need to take that count as well. For which I am not getting the Regex. Please Help

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to actually fix the leak? ;)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to match a line with `DEFService` only, when a line containing `many open files` comes after it and if there are no other service lines between them. You can do that by allowing for optional lines in-between the two, as long as they only start with error or warning, for example: `\[DEFService@.*[\r\n]+(?:^(?:ERROR|WARNING).*[\r\n]+)*?^.*?many\s+open\s+files`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/I51ATD/1).

Comment: You should post a language tag.  Regexes don't usually work in isolation.  And you did say you wanted to count the occurrences.

Comment: @WJS It also wasn't clear to me whether the OP meant to count the occurrences of the 'many' lines after a service line or count the service lines that have at least one 'many' line, but I picked the latter since that's what could be done using Notepad++ and a regex similar to the one they tried.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to take the count of every Service , How many times the "many open files" error message has occurred for that Service.

There is no need to use regular expressions as you can do it like this.

- create a map to hold the counts
- read a string from the file.

  - if the string starts with a service, capture it and use as a map key
  - else, sum the count in the map for that service if the line contains the error

This presumes that the log files are consistently written.  For example, if the line starts with a `[` then the service will be encapsulated within a closing `]`.

```
Map<String, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
String currentService = "";
String logFile = <source of error messages>

try ( Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File(logFile))) {
    while (readFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = readFile.nextLine();
        if (line.startsWith("[")) {
             currentService = line.substring(1, line.indexOf("]"));
        } else if (line.contains("many open files.")) {
            count.merge(currentService, 1, Integer::sum);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

count.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
XYZService@=12
DEFService@=23
ABCService=12
```

Note that  the above can be incorporated into any code that is currently reading the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use the J mode of enhanced text editor -**EmEditor** to handle it. It's easy to understand the progress.

Total 4 steps:

1. Add a square bracket **[** at the end of the file firstly , since the regex expression will use Positive Look-around **(?=\[)**.Otherwise, last match will get lost.
2. Press [Ctrl+H] to open replace dialog , type search and replace expression.
3. Click button "Advanced... ", and then activate option

> "Regular Expression “.” Can Match Newline Characters"

don't forget to set

> "Additional Lines to Search for Regular Expressions:"

to **30 or any other number**, which should be larger than maximum lines of checked lines.If you can't understand the option, you can set 100 or larger number, but it need longer time to handle the file.

4. Click button "Extract" to get wanted result.

**Regular Expression :**

Find: `^(\[[A-Z]{3}Service@?\]:)(.+?)(?=^\[)`

Replace : `\J "\1"+"\2".match(/many open files/g).length`

**Explain of Find Expression：**

`^(\[[A-Z]{3}Service@?\]:)`   this pattern will match [DEFService@],[ABCService],[XYZService@].....

`(.+?)(?=^\[)`  this pattern will match all lines until meeting square bracket **[**

The whole pattern will match all lines between [DEFService@],[ABCService],[XYZService@].....

**Explain of Replace Expression :**
\J is J mode , which is must prefix .

`"\1"` is the first back-reference.

`"\2"` is the second back-reference, they are lines between [DEFService@],[ABCService],[XYZService@].....

`match(/many open files/g)` method will find all "many open files" and output to an array. Use `length` property to get the quantity of "many open files".

See the screenshot please.
[image]

Here's also a Gif file.
[image]